# Intersection between a array and matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a array generated as `A=randperm(1024,256)` and a matrix `B` of size (5,256) with each row  generated using `randperm(1024,256)` in matlab. I want to find the count of common numbers between `A` and `B(1,:)`, then between `A` and `B(1:2,:)`, likewise upto `B(1:5,:)`. I tried doing it as done below and it works but I want it for U=20 and higher number in that case it will be messy to write the code as I have done. Can anyone suggest better code or technique for this.

```
N=1024;
k=256;
U=5;
A=randperm(N,K);

    for u=1:U
        user(u,:)=randperm(N,k); 
    end

i(1)=numel(intersect(A,user(1,:)));

i(2)=numel(intersect(A,([user(1,:),user(2,:)])));

i(3)=numel(intersect(A,([user(1,:),user(2,:),user(3,:)])));

i(4)=numel(intersect(A,([user(1,:),user(2,:),user(3,:),user(4,:)])));

i(5)=numel(intersect(A,([user(1,:),user(2,:),user(3,:),user(4,:),user(5,:)])));
```

Comment: You could try looping

Comment: true but I am not getting proper idea to do looping...

Comment: Give a try to loop it and then show us your try. Lets see how it goes

Comment: Do note that you can count the intersection for each row separately, then add the appropriate counts to generate required output.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
result = cumsum(sum(ismember(B, A), 2));
```

How it works:

1. `ismember(B, A)` is a matrix with entries `0` or `1` indicating if each entry of `B` is in `A`.
2. `sum(..., 2)` computed the sum of each row. So it gives the number of entries of each row of `B` that are in `A`.
3. `cumsum` computes the cumulative sum of that. So its `n`-th entry gives the number of entries in the first `n` rows of `B` that are in `A`.

Comment: Now I got a new doubt...lets say I have 'A=[2 5 7 10 15] B=[1 5 10 12 13;4 5 8 10 11]' when I follow your suggestion I will get 'result=[2;4]' but since 5 and 10 are present in both rows I want 'result=[2;2]'. i.e., I want to check how many numbers of A are in first row of B then I want check how many numbers of A are present in 1st and 2nd row of B combined.

Comment: @user33184 That's tricikier, because the `10` in `B` is in different columns for each row. It can be done, but the approaches will be totally different to those used for this question. So I suggest you ask a new question for that

Comment: thank you...I resolved it myself using another method now.